# Just a contraction of indices

Tags: tensor-calculus

I came across a contraction which is not giving the desired result. This is a toy problem in how to get a supergravity theory in low energy limit of a superstring theory using the vanishing of beta function in the $\sigma$ model, however there is no use of this context.

What I want to ask is contracting d and m in the following expression where T is torsion two-form and  R is the curvature two-form.

The expression is $T^{[c}_{[pq}\delta^{d]}_{m]} +2a\partial_{[p}R^{cd}_{{qm}]}=0$

There is one extra condition $R^{mc}_{mq}=0$.
It is clear that second term would look like $\frac{2a}{3}\partial_m R^{mc}_{pq}$, apart from some sign probably.
The first term however after writting out explicitly gives $\frac{1}{6}T^c_{pq}$ ( one can eliminate terms like $T^c_{cm}$ which can shown to be cancel ), which gives something like

$T^c_{pq}+4a\partial_m R^{mc}_{pq}$=0 ( May be there is a minus sign before $4a\partial_m R^{mc}_{pq}$ but that is not the problem). The problem however is that the result should be following one

$T^c_{pq}+\frac{4a}{9}\partial_m R^{mc}_{pq}$=0 and I don't know how he is getting the factor of 9 there. For reference one can look at Castellani ' Supergravity and superstrings: a geometric perspective vol. 3' around page 1850.